# How to write a code and measure time sent from udp client to udp server in python?

Tags: python, sockets, udp

```
import socket
server=port = 2160
client_socket = socket.socket(AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
input_s = 'hello, server!'  # the message
client_socket.sendto(bytes(inpus_s, encoding='utf8'),('127.0.0.1', server_port)) # sending message
input_s_modified, adress = client_socket.recvfrom(65535) # receiving from server
print ('[CLIENT] Response from server {}, is: "{}"'.format(adress,  str(input_s_modified.decode('utf8'))))
client_socket.close() # closing socket
```

Comment: You can include the sent time in the packet using `time.time()`, then minus it from the `time.time()` of the server. This is measured in seconds.

Comment: @Xiddoc , can you please send me how code should look like? I should get output how many seconds passed from sending the message until server responded.

Comment: Are you writing code for the client AND for the server, or only for the client? Because you will need to be able to modify both sides in order to get the time difference.

Comment: @xiddoc, ok I will modify both sides. Can you send me the code please?

Comment: On StackOverflow people don't write code for you, they help you understand how to fix your problem. I have, however, written some code samples along with my explanation to help you understand how to get to a solution. If my answer helps, be sure to click the checkmark on the left of my answer to mark it as valid.

Comment: @Xiddoc, I am almost done but I am getting an error like this: Exception has occurred: TypeError
'module' object is not callable
  File "F:\python.exerecices\PythonNetProgramming\UDPprotokol\udp_server3.py", line 14, in <module>
    time_dif = time() - float(client_time)

Answer (score 1):

You can get the time difference by sending the current timestamp, then having the server send back the difference between the server time and the time that it received in its data.

On the client side, you can prepend the data like so:

```py
# Import the time module
from time import time
...
# Add prefix with client timestamp
input_s = str(time()) + '|hello, server!'  # the message
```

And in the backend / server side code, you can modify the data like so:

```py
# Get the client time
client_time = data.split(b"|")[0]
# Get the time difference
tiime_dif = time() - float(client_time)
# Modify the send data to include the time difference
connection.sendall(str(time_dif).encode() + "|".encode() + data)
```

When you put all of this info together, you end up with something like this:

```py
# CLIENT

import socket
# Import the time module
from time import time
server=port = 2160
client_socket = socket.socket(AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
# Add prefix with client timestamp
input_s = str(time()) + '|hello, server!'  # the message
client_socket.sendto(bytes(inpus_s, encoding='utf8'),('127.0.0.1', server_port)) # sending message
input_s_modified, adress = client_socket.recvfrom(65535) # receiving from server
print ('[CLIENT] Response from server {}, is: "{}"'.format(adress,  str(input_s_modified.decode('utf8'))))
client_socket.close() # closing socket
```

```py
# SERVER

# Get the client time
client_time = data.split(b"|")[0]
# Get the time difference
tiime_dif = time() - float(client_time)
# Modify the send data to include the time difference
connection.sendall(str(time_dif).encode() + "|".encode() + data)
```

Comment: I wrote client side , but on server side I couldnt complete code. I make somwhere mistake

Comment: in server script there is a data, and connection are not recognized. What is the problem? Also, I do not understand  data.split(b"|")[0] syntax.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand what you are saying. Maybe clear up by showing some errors & code?

Comment: sorry I did not explain well. I think # Client part is fine . could you send me full server side of the code please?

Comment: I do not have the full server side code, you will need to write that yourself. In my Server code, I wrote the code with the assumption that the data that the server received is put in the variable `data`, as you can see in the first line- I take the text from `data` and split it so I can get the time. You will need to modify my code slightly to work with whatever code you already have written in your server.

Comment: can you please try to run the code you sent me , I think its not full and I dont know how to complete it

Comment: yes for data , I've changed data = server.recv(128) like this and its ok butt connection last line of code does not work ?

Answer (score 0):

```
# import socket
# Import the time module
from time import time
server_port = 2160
client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
# Add prefix with client timestamp
input_s = str(time()) + '|hello, server!'  # the message
client_socket.sendto(bytes(input_s, encoding='utf8'),('127.0.0.1', server_port)) # 
sending message
input_s_modified, adress = client_socket.recvfrom(65535) # receiving from server
print ('[CLIENT] Response from server {}, is: "{}"'.format(adress,  
str(input_s_modified.decode('utf8'))))
client_socket.close() # closing socket
```

Comment: # this is client